# sqldf--select nested in another select doesn't work

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm working with the sqldf package in R. I want to create a dataset whose students' ID are excluded from another dataset. My code looks like:

```
delete <- sqldf("select distinct ID from A where ...") 
B<-sqldf("select * from A where ID not in ('select ID from delete')")
```

After running the code I found B is exactly the same as A. It seems sqldf doesn't recogonize the nested select statement.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has these problems:

1. there is actually no nested select at all in the code shown.  The statement is requesting all ID's that do not equal the string `'select ID from delete'`.  Remove the quotes.
2. `delete` is an SQLite keyword.  Either use a different name for your data.frame or put the name `delete` in quotes within the SQL statement so it knows not to treat it as a keyword.
3. next time please state the question in a reproducible form.  See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Making these three changes we have the following where A has the ID's 1,2,3,4, delete has the IDs 1,2 and B has the ID's 3,4.

```
library(sqldf)    
A <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4))

delete <- sqldf("select distinct ID from A where ID < 3")
B <- sqldf("select * from A where ID not in (select ID from 'delete')")
```